# Web API oauth bearer token authentication doesn't work in Edge browser

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth, access-token, microsoft-edge

I use Web API oauth bearer token authentication + AngularJs [from here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)
It works in another browsers, but in Microsoft Edge it doesn`t work.
In this browser I get token from server, but still stay in this page,
although browser have to redirect to another page.
I think the problem happens when I set token data to local Storage.
I do this by this way

```
if (loginData.useRefreshTokens) {
            localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName, refreshToken: response.refresh_token, useRefreshTokens: true });
        }
        else {
            localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName, refreshToken: "", useRefreshTokens: false });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I do http get request to web api method which check if current user has required role by this way

AngularJS

```
 $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "api/Models/CheckAccess/"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        if (response.data === true) {
            $location.path(page);
        }
        else
        {
            authServiceFactory.logOut();
            $location.path("login");
        }

    });
```

WebApi Method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public bool CheckAccess()
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;        
        var userRole = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                           .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
        if (userRole=="Hauler")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }      
    }
```

In Edge browser it`s always return false. I solve this problem by this way

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Hauler")]
    public bool CheckAccess()
    {      
        return true;
    }
```